# How to reject call on HTC desire Z?

Tags: calls, htc-desire-z

Is it possible to reject call somehow when screen is locked as the same moment I unlock the screen, I acctualy accept the call?

Comment: Actually I solved it with removing screen lock option completely using application "No lock". Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just to answer this question in case future users have it.

I believe in HTC Sense when a call comes in and the screen lock is there it should say slide up to reject the call and down to answer.